# Show hidden element using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show hidden element using `jquery`. I use bootstrap I have `div` with `hidden` class.

```
<div id='some-div' class='hidden'>
some elements here
</div>
```

trying to call:

```
$('#some-div').show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#some-div').removeClass('hidden');
```

That actually removes the class `hidden` which makes it hidden, resulting in it being displayed. Another way of doing it is the following:

```
<div id="some-div" style:"display:none;">
some elements here
</div>
```

And then in jQuery:

```
$('#some-div').show();
```

But this doesn't use the class `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to also be able to hide the element again, you can use

`$('#some-div').toggleClass('hidden');`

This will remove the "hidden" class the first time it is called and then add it back on the subsequent call. See http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/